# Provide local maven dependency to AWS CodeDeploy

Tags: amazon-web-services, spring-boot, maven, aws-pipeline

I develop/maintain a utility project that is installed to my local maven repo, which allows my SaaS project to build.

I've integrated the SaaS project into an AWS Pipeline, however it fails on CodeBuild phase because the local utility dependency cannot be resolved.

Is there a way to instruct Maven to import the dependency jar into the project such that it can be included in the push to Github and reachable by CodeBuild?